# How to highlight my Master's thesis grade in CV

Tags: thesis, cv

My Master's thesis was granted 9/10. It was the highest score even given for a thesis since the progam was founded (8 years sonner). How can I highlight it in my resume without looking ostentatious?
Thanks!

Comment: While "highest score ever" might sound good, the fact that the program was founded only 8 years ago makes that a pretty weak thing.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft Depending on the number of students, it might not be. Compare a program that exists for 10 years and graduates 10 students a year to a program that exists for 5 years, but graduates 100 students a year.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Most masters programs have been in existence for at least 20 if not 50 years, hence why 8 years is not much time for comparisons.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft No, masters programs might have been around that long in places where a master was common, but for example in Germany a diploma used to be common 10 years ago and there first change was in bachelors programs, so a lot of masters programs have been changed from diploma to bachelor/master only ten or 8 years ago. As a not to the question, without being familiar with the grading system and how hard it would be to get a 9/10 I would learn nothing from you stating it, other than it's probably not a bad thing.

Comment: This is usually mentioned in the recommendation letters by the professors and/or in the motivational letter. I'd leave it out of the CV.

Answer (score 4):

Great mark and well done! However, this is hard to mention without looking a little ostentatious as you say, so it's probably better to just include your overall degree result. Presumably if you got such a high mark for your thesis, you would have attained a distinction for your degree. If you did not do so and attained a pass or merit, and you include your thesis mark, this could raise questions as to why you ended up getting a lesser mark in your degree. If you *did* get a distinction overall - then congratulations - and that mark would speak for itself. If you really do want to include it, do so in the most minimalist way, such as **Thesis - *Thesis Title*** **(9/10). Supervisor - Dr XX XXXX.**

Comment: Note that in some cultures, there are no distinctions or merits that can be attained.

Comment: @AndrejaKo I cannot tell which country the question asker is from, so I have to make do with my own domestic grading system for now. I'm sure the asker can apply the sytem used in the answer to their own academic culture/country's system.

Comment: Actually, I want to apply for a program in Canada. Does it make any difference?